# Combining a list of tuple dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataset where every two rows needs to be group together and combined into one longer row, basically duplicating the headers and adding the 2nd row to the 1st. Here is a small sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,1,2,2],'Var1': ['A', 2, 'C', 7], 'Var2': ['B', 5, 'D', 9]})
print(df)

ID Var1 Var2
1    A    B
1    2    5
2    C    D
2    7    9
```

I will have to group the rows my 'ID' so therefore I ran:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['ID'])
grp_lst = list(grouped)
```

This resulted in a list of tuples grouped by id where element 1 is the grouped dataframe I would like to combine.

The desired result is a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
ID Var1 Var2  ID.1  Var1.1  Var2.1
1    A    B     1       2       5
2    C    D     2       7       9
```

I have to do this over a large data set, where the "ID" is used to group the rows and then I want to basically add the bottom row to end on the top.

Any help would be appreciated and I assume there is a much easier way to do this than I am doing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there always even number of rows (that is two rows per `ID`) ? and is the `ID` column already sorted?

Comment: Yes it is always two rows per ID and is sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try:

```
i = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().astype(str)
df_out = df.set_index([df['ID'].values, i]).stack().unstack([2, 1])
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('.'.join)
```

**Details:**

`group` the dataframe on `ID` and use `cumcount` to create sequential counter to uniquely identify the rows per `ID`:

```
>>> i

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
dtype: object
```

Create multilevel index in the dataframe with the first level set to `ID` values and second level set to the above sequential counter, then use `stack` followed by `unstack` to reshape the dataframe in the desired format:

```
>>> df_out

  ID Var1 Var2 ID Var1 Var2 #---> Level 0 columns
   0    0    0  1    1    1 #---> Level 1 columns
1  1    A    B  1    2    5
2  2    C    D  2    7    9
```

Finally flatten the multilevel columns using `Index.map` with `join`:

```
>>> df_out

  ID.0 Var1.0 Var2.0 ID.1 Var1.1 Var2.1
1    1      A      B    1      2      5
2    2      C      D    2      7      9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `numpy` to `reshape` the dataframe first then `tile` the columns and create new dataframe from reshape values and tiled columns:

```
s = df.shape[1]
c = np.tile(df.columns, 2) + '.' + (np.arange(s * 2) // s).astype(str)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, s * 2), columns=c)
```

---

```
>>> df_out

  ID.0 Var1.0 Var2.0 ID.1 Var1.1 Var2.1
0    1      A      B    1      2      5
1    2      C      D    2      7      9
```

Note: This method is only applicable if you have two rows per `ID` and the `ID` columns is already sorted.